# .env data not accessible

Tags: python-3.x, gitignore, dotenv

I made .env and .gitignore files along with some other files. .env is in gitignore and I have pushed all the files on GitHub. Following are the results :

- .env is untracked and not pushed to repository [ correct behavior ]
- the data in .env file is inaccessible [ token of none type found ]

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

load_dotenv()

TOKEN = os.getenv('TOKEN')
```

I have tried pushing .env manually on github and all the things go well, I can access the data in .env
However pushing with git bash, it can't be accessed. How can I access the data using .gitignore and .env both??

Comment: Before you do `load_dotenv()` do a `os.getcwd()` which should print the directory in which `.env` file will be searched.

Answer (score 1):

Try `os.environ.get` to get the token from `.env`.

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

load_dotenv()

TOKEN = os.environ.get("TOKEN")
print(TOKEN)
```

Also, Make sure the `.env` file is in the same directory of the python file. If it is not, you'll have to join the directories, or use the `find_dotenv` function, like this:

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

TOKEN = os.environ.get("TOKEN")
print(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Did not work, when I use os.environ.get("TOKEN"). Again it returns 'NoneType' object. 
 Also, I have put .env and bot.py in same directory.

Comment: Are you running the script from the project root directory? If the script is in a subdirectory, and you place the `.env` in the same directory, `dotenv` looks for the `.env` file in the project root. Here is an [example project](https://github.com/cdesch/env_example) to show two situations of the above code working.

Comment: Yes both .env and script.py are in root folder